# codeigniter login validation not validating rules

Tags: validation, codeigniter-3

am using  codeigniter 3.0.4 .here this Here the action send to the controler(first.php)not validating anything it will turn to else statement and display login page again(as set as in redirect('welcome/login_page');). my register function in the same controller working good. what is the exact problem ..please help me to find it.thanks.

..............the controller(first.php).....

```
public function signup_validation(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email',       'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|callback_validate_credentials');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

 if($this->form_validation->run() ){

$user_id= $this->model_users->get_id($this->input->post('email'));
$user_status = $this->model_users->get_status($this->input->post('email'));

$data = array (
      'user_id' => $user_id,
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'user_status' =>$user_status,
        'is_logged_in' => 1
    );

 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
      if ($this->session->userdata('user_status')=='0') {
    redirect('main/admins');
  }
  elseif ($this->session->userdata('user_status')=='1') {
    redirect('main/members');
  }else{

        redirect('welcome/login_page');
      }





 }

public function  validate_credentials(){

$this->load->model('model_users');

    if($this->model_users->can_log_in() ){

 return TRUE;
 } else {
$this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials', 'Invalid useername(email-id) or password. !');
return FALSE;
 }
```

}

....the view(login.php)......

```
                       echo form_open("first/signup_validation");
                   echo'<div class="row">';
                echo'<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">';
                echo'<label for="email">Email<span></span></label>';
                echo'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">';
                                        echo'</div>';
            echo'<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">';
            echo'<label for="password">Password<span></span></label>';
        echo'<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">';
                                        echo'</div>';
                                    echo'</div>';


                                    $data2 = array(

                                        'class'       => 'btn btn-default',
                                    );

                                         echo form_submit($data2, 'Login');

                                 echo form_close('');
        ?>
```

Comment: See [the "upgrading to CodeIgniter v 3" page, step 13](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-13-check-for-usage-of-the-xss-clean-form-validation-rule).  You should not be using `xss_clean` as a validation rule.

Comment: Thanks.removed xss_clean. but still as the same... no error messages.!

Comment: `echo form_close('')` should be `echo form_close()`, but not sure that would make any difference.  Since you're not putting a string inside `form_close()`, then there is no point in using it.  Just use a `</form>` tag instead.  See:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_close

Comment: thanks my friend.. but it's not the problem. am still not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">';
```

Your `input` elements don't contain a `name` attribute.  The `name` is what's used as the identifier in the validation rule.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email'... // <- 'email' is the name attribute
```

Do this...

```
echo'<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">';
```